# After opening a folder in Sublime Text 3, how do I open two files at once?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using MacOS 10.12.

I open a folder in Sublime Text 3 and I click a file.
The file then appears as a tab on the right side.
If I don't edit it and try to open another file, the previous one will be replaced by the new file.
My question is: how do I open the second one without having to edit the first one?

For now, my solution is to press a blankspace and delete it in the first file (so nothing changes here). And then open the second file.
This is annoying, and I figure there might be a better solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the following preference is set:

```
// Preview file contents when clicking on a file in the side bar. Double
// clicking or editing the preview will open the file and assign it a tab.
"preview_on_click": true,
```

This means that a single left click on a file in the sidebar will open a preview/transient tab. Single left clicking on another file will replace that tab with a preview of the new file. As you have noticed, editing the file in some way will convert the tab from a preview to a persistent tab. Setting this preference to `false` will mean that single clicking will do nothing. There is currently no option to get the file to open in a persistent tab from a single click.

Regardless of this preference, double left clicking will open the file in a tab that will stay.

Comment: I didn't know it's "preview". Now I get it. Thank you.